# Call to method with a thread inside implies a wait?

Tags: java, java-threads

I have a method that writes a file and it can be a bit slow. So I did this to avoid blocking the rest of actions:

```
// things A
method();
// things B

public void method(){
 new Thread(() -> {
    // slow stuff
 }).start();
}
```

However it still takes a while until things B are executed after things A and I was wondering if I should do this instead:

```
// things A
new Thread(() -> {
    method();
}).start();
// things B

public void method(){
    // slow stuff
}
```

Or, in other words, does calling a method with a thread inside it imply waiting for the method to end, and therefore the thread?

Just to clarify things: I want to know if both options would be the same or if in the first option the thread should finish for the B instructions to start.

Comment: When `method` is executed within your anonymous thread, your main thread **does not** wait for the anonymous thread to complete `method`. Thread are independent instances of execution. Your main thread should invoke a join on your anonymous thread in order to wait for its completion. So, to answer your question: "no, invoking `new Thread( () -> {...} ).start()` does not imply waiting for its completion".

Comment: No, that method call is trivial compared to the cost of going out to I/O and writing the file. It's even trivial compared to the cost of creating the `Thread`. If the threaded solution is stalling your program, then there's something else going on that's not shown in the code sample here. Either that or you're on an embedded system with only one core (in which case multithreading won't save you since it's all still happening on the same processor)

Comment: @Dan, yes, I get that. My question is just the opposite. In the first case, when the method is called, with the thread inside the method, should the method (and therefore the thread) end for the things B to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does calling a method with a thread on it imply waiting for the method to end, and therefore the thread?*

No. To highlight that the thread isn't a factor, I took your original code:

```
method();
// things B

public void method(){
 new Thread(() -> {
    // slow stuff
 }).start();
}
```

And sprinkled a bunch of `System.out.println()` calls throughout:

- one before calling `method()`, and one right after
- one at the start of `method()`, and one at the end
- one at the start of the thread body, and one at the end

Also:

- the thread does "slow stuff" by calling `Thread.sleep()` for 2 seconds
- each `println()` includes current date+time
- the output is crudely formatted with indentation to show the start/end pairs of each output

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class ThreadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main >> " + LocalDateTime.now());
        new ThreadExample().method();
        System.out.println("main << " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("  method >> " + LocalDateTime.now());
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("    thread >> " + LocalDateTime.now());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("    thread << " + LocalDateTime.now());
        }).start();
        System.out.println("  method << " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Output below, which shows a few things:

- the first+second output lines in `main` (before and after calling `method()`) are basically instantaneous – 09:10:22.036305 start, 09:10:22.037957 end, for a difference of 0.001652 seconds
- same for `method()`, nearly instantaneous with start of 09:10:22.037564 and end of 09:10:22.037897, which is a difference of 0.000333 seconds
- the start and finish outputs in `thread` are where the waiting is, starting at 09:10:22.037920, ending at 09:10:24.041840; total difference of 2.00392 seconds which is the 2 seconds we asked for with `Thread.sleep()` plus the tiny amount of execution time similar to the others (0.00392)
- perhaps most importantly for this question, it's clear that both the original caller (in `main()`) and `method()` both finish before `thread` finishes ~2 seconds later

```
main >> 2022-06-17T09:10:22.036305
  method >> 2022-06-17T09:10:22.037564
  method << 2022-06-17T09:10:22.037897
    thread >> 2022-06-17T09:10:22.037920
main << 2022-06-17T09:10:22.037957
    thread << 2022-06-17T09:10:24.041840
```